# Django Ajax - $.get method success function executed without ANY server-side view called

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, pagination

Deleted the previous question to clarify it a bit.

I have A Django powered website and a template with dynamically populated table.

Template:

```
<table id = 'my_table'>
   <thead>
      ......
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () 
{
    refresh_vendors_list_table();
});

function refresh_vednors_list_table()
{
    $.get("/ajax_refresh_vendors_list_table/", function(response) 
    {
        $('#my_table').find('tbody').html(response);
    });
}
```

View:

```
def ajax_refresh_vendors_list_table(request):
    template = 'vendors/vendors_list_paginator.html'
    vendors_qs = vendors_qs.filter(...)
    context = {'vendors_qs':vendors_qs}
    return render_to_response(template,
                              context,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template for the table (vendors_list_paginator.html)

```
{% load el_pagination_tags %}

{% paginate vendors_qs %}   

{% for vendor in vendors_qs %}
    <tr>
         ......
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% show_more_table %}
```

When pressing each row in the table, I am redirected to the corresponding vendor's profile. After editing the profile, I press the back button and coming back again to the table page. At this stage, I start to debug the `$.get("/ajax_refresh_vendors_list_table/", data, function(response)` 
I also put a breakpoint at `template = 'vendors/vendors_list_paginator.html'` (let's call it **breakpoint A**)

A very strange behaviour is observed in `$.get` function: the corresponding Django view is not called (I don't see my app stop at breakpoing A) and yet `$('#my_table').find('tbody').html(response);` is executed directly as if the $.get function should execute successfully !!!!

**In other words, $.get function is executed without any participation of server-side** (I emphasize the word any. At first I thought that maybe I messed up the URLConf file and some other view was called. To check this, I cleared up the Django IDE console prior to pressing the browser back button and after pressing it, saw nothing in the Django IDE console meaning that $.get request successfully executed without ANY VIEW CALLED !!!)
Does it have something to do with pagination ? I am completely lost. Help please !

**UPDATE**

As per Sardorbek's answer, I've included the following decorators before the definition of `ajax_refresh_vendors_list_table`

```
@require_http_methods(["GET"])
@never_cache
def ajax_refresh_vendors_list_table(request):
   ...
```

Comment: does it stop on your breakpoint if you open `/ajax_refresh_vendors_list_table/` manually?

Comment: try looking into browser's console and place breakpoint in js I still don't see where is your `data` variable coming from?

Comment: Hm... Looks like your browser is caching this request. Trying wrapping this url with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Try moving `never_cache` to the top so it will be before `require_http_methods`

Answer (score 1):

Hm... Looks like your browser is caching this request. Trying wrapping this url with [`never_cache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache)

```
never_cache(url(...))
```

Comment: Sardorbek, unfortunately, your answer worked once - I don't know how - but then when I began to test it, it turned out that the rows didn't update again. I provide my updated code, maybe it's my fault and I am doing something wrong with cache. Could you please confirm that I am doing everythink correctly ?